# finding absolute straight lines/ rectangles for contours in opencv

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

While trying to detect the straight lines in an image, I'm unable to find the Hough transform of the image.

I have first converted the image to grayscale but unable to find the straight lines.
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
Thus, can you help me to make the contours which were detected as pure straight lines/rectangles. Such that I can easily find the horizontal lines(i will do it later) in the image.

```
def hou():
   import math
   img = cv2.imread('image5GR.jpg')
   #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
   minLineLength = 20
   maxLineGap = 10
   lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,math.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
   for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
      cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
   while True:
     cv2.imshow('houghlines',img)
     if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()

import cv2    
hou()
```

Finally, the image I am getting, which isn't appropriate(only shows a small green line at the bottom)
[image: output]

whereas, I am expecting it to be as:
[image: edited output image]

Thanks